# Smoother accordion show/hide

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project, using Twitter Bootstrap as it basis (ok, along with CodeIgniter), and i'm having an issue with a nested accordion (each primary accordion entry contains a lot of data).

**Here's the page :**  (Username: `peraspera` , Password: `adastra`)

http://patternz.drkameleon.com/project/results/823990/3/extended

*(please have a look at the "Results" tab, that's where the nested accordion is)*

---

What is that I could do in order to make this whole thing smoother? Any ideas?

**P.S.** I've already disabled animations, that doesn't seem to help a lot (especially, given that the data inside the accordion may be even more than there currently is)

Comment: @DavidNormington I have already included Username and Password in the original post (username : "peraspera", password : "adastra")

Comment: Maybe posting the piece of code handling the accordion animation ?

Comment: @RomainBraun I haven't written ANYTHING regarding the animation or the accordion. What I'm using is the default accordion control found in Twitter Bootstrap, that's all.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood. No need to yell.

Comment: @RomainBraun Not yelling, just... emphasizing... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the CSS of your accordeon, use the CSS3 transition feature: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/

```
-moz-transition : height 1s;
-webkit-transition : height 1s;
-o-transition : height 1s;
transition : height 1s;
```